# Calling with "shop!"

Tags: meaning

In a scene in a film when a man entering in an police office hits the table calling bell and says "Shop!". What does "shop" mean?

Comment: I haven't heard this, but Cop Shop is slang for a police station.

Answer (score 4):

In more trusting times, a small shopkeeper might leave the counter unattended while they went into the back room. A customer coming in would call 'Shop!' meaning 'There's someone in the shop waiting to be served'.

Presumably in your film there was no-one at the front desk in the police station.